# What is the transconductance value of a given bjt?

Tags: bjt

In a BJT transistor V<sub>be</sub> is 0.7V and reverse saturation current is 10<sup>-15</sup> A. What is transconductance value ?

Comment: how to find the value ?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\$g_m = \frac{I_C}{V_T}\$

where \$I_C = I_S \cdot e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}\$

So, \$I_C = 10^{−15} \cdot e^{\frac{0.7}{0.025}}\$

\$I_C = 1.446257 mA\$

Hence, \$g_m = \frac{1.446257 mA}{0.025 V} = 57.850282 mS\$

Comment: The OP said 10^-15 not 13. Also gm = Ic/Vt? do you mean Vbe?

Comment: Vt means thermal voltage. Typically it is about 0.025V at  room temperature. By mistake Ic value changed from 10^(-15) to 10^(-13)

Comment: Fixed error, formatted math.

Comment: why is Gm, Ic/Vt? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andyaka This is about transconductance of the Small Signal BJT

Comment: shouldnt Gm be Ic/Vbe @basil

Comment: @Andyaka No, it's right.  Gm is the derivative of Ic, dIc/dVbe, which agrees with the OP's equation.

Comment: @Bitrex the answerer is saying Gm = Ic/Vt - I'm saying it shouldn't be "Vt" but "Vbe" - help me out - am I going daft?

Comment: @Andyaka if you differentiate Ic wrt Vbe, you get Ic/Vt.  Also, Gm is the reciprocal of the dynamic emitter impedance Re, which is Vt/Ic.  To confirm,  it's Vt, not Vbe.

Comment: @Andyaka For the small-signal hybrid pi model of a BJT, gm = Ic/Vt. The original answer is correct. I don't have my electronics textbook handy, but take this wikipedia article for now: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model#Bipolar_junction_.28BJT.29_parameters